# ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'int32' with no type

Tags: c++, c, linux, build, android-source

Trying to build an AOSP version and got this error

> error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'int32' with no type
>
> error: typedef 'int32' is initialized (use decltype instead)
>
> error: 'loc_event_cb_f_type' was not declared in this scope

this is the declaration that throws the error

```
typedef int32 (loc_event_cb_f_type)(
    rpc_loc_client_handle_type            loc_handle,             /* handle of the client */
    rpc_loc_event_mask_type               loc_event,              /* event mask           */
    const rpc_loc_event_payload_u_type*   loc_event_payload       /* payload              */
);
```

this is the complete file: /libloc_api-rpc/rpc_inc/loc_api_rpc_glue.h

```
#ifndef LOC_API_RPC_GLUE_H
#define LOC_API_RPC_GLUE_H

/* Include RPC headers */
#include "rpc_inc/loc_api_common.h"
#include "rpc_inc/loc_api.h"
#include "rpc_inc/loc_api_cb.h"
#include "rpc_inc/loc_api_fixup.h"

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

/* Boolean */
/* Other data types in comdef.h are defined in rpc stubs, so fix it here */
typedef unsigned char boolean;
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

extern int loc_api_glue_init(void);
extern int loc_api_null(void);

typedef int32 (loc_event_cb_f_type)(
      rpc_loc_client_handle_type            loc_handle,             /* handle of the client */
      rpc_loc_event_mask_type               loc_event,              /* event mask           */
      const rpc_loc_event_payload_u_type*   loc_event_payload       /* payload              */
);

extern rpc_loc_client_handle_type loc_open(
      rpc_loc_event_mask_type       event_reg_mask,
      loc_event_cb_f_type* event_callback
);

extern int32 loc_close
(
      rpc_loc_client_handle_type handle
);

extern int32 loc_start_fix
(
      rpc_loc_client_handle_type handle
);

extern int32 loc_stop_fix
(
      rpc_loc_client_handle_type handle
);

extern int32 loc_ioctl
(
      rpc_loc_client_handle_type           handle,
      rpc_loc_ioctl_e_type                 ioctl_type,
      rpc_loc_ioctl_data_u_type*           ioctl_data
);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif /* LOC_API_RPC_GLUE_H */
```

do you have any idea?

Comment: Should it be `int32_t`?

Comment: When I tried to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) from the code shown, I could not reproduce the error.  Please create an MCVE that does reproduce the problem — but it's quite probable that you'll find the solution while you're creating the MCVE and you can then delete this question.

Comment: FWIW: my non-repro attempted MCVE used: `#include <stdint.h>` and `typedef int32_t int32; struct rpc_loc_client_handle_type { int h; }; struct rpc_loc_event_mask_type { int mask 4 ; }; struct rpc_loc_event_payload_u_type; typedef int32 (loc_event_cb_f_type)( rpc_loc_client_handle_type loc_handle, rpc_loc_event_mask_type loc_event, const rpc_loc_event_payload_u_type *loc_event_payload ); extern loc_event_cb_f_type loc_type;` — formatting in comments isn't good.

Comment: @luserdroog do you know if int32 is defined only on windows?

Comment: @JoseMiguelArroyave I'm sorry, I don't know. I know that `int32_t` is a standard type in C if you include `stdint.h`. I use the cygwin environment on windows so I can pretend it's unix.

Comment: ok. Thanks both of you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that int32 was not defined or included anywhere

as @luserdroog wrote,

> Should it be int32_t?

int32_t and other intX_t typedefs are defined in /usr/include/stdint.h, so it can be solved by replacing all int32 by int32_t or, as @JonathanLeffler proposed, defining the int32 type, which is more convenient and clean.

> typedef uint32_t uint32;

but to solve this issue for other files,

adding this declarations to /usr/include/stdint.h will work

```
#ifndef __uint8_defined
typedef uint8_t uint8;
# define __uint8_defined
#endif

#ifndef __int8_defined
typedef int8_t int8;
# define __int8_defined
#endif

#ifndef __uint16_defined
typedef uint16_t uint16;
# define __uint16_defined
#endif

#ifndef __int16_defined
typedef int16_t int16;
# define __int16_defined
#endif

#ifndef __uint32_defined
typedef uint32_t uint32;
# define __uint32_defined
#endif

#ifndef __int32_defined
typedef int32_t int32;
# define __int32_defined
#endif

#ifndef __uint64_defined
typedef uint64_t uint64;
# define __uint64_defined
#endif

#ifndef __int64_defined
typedef int64_t int64;
# define __int64_defined
#endif
```